# Is it possible to add a static object to a list in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of static classes I would like to access easily by adding them all to a List.

Is there a way to add these static classes to a list? I get a "This type is used like a variable" error.

```
public static class PCM1_Setup : IGUI_to_BFC
{
    //PCM1_FORMAT
    public static void Setup_toBFC()
    {
        //uses the checkboxes to update the BFC
        //Determine the value to write to the field based on the check boxes
        RegmapInputReader.BitField BF;
        GB.BFC.name_to_BitField_Dict.TryGetValue("PCM1_FORMAT", out BF);
    }

    public static void Setup_fromBFC()
    {
        //Sets up the check boxes from the BFC
    }
}

public static class PC2
{
    List<IGUI_to_BFC> abe = new List<IGUI_to_BFC>();
    PC2()
    {
        abe.Add(PCM1_Setup); //ERROR HERE----------------------
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what your final goal is... It looks like you trying to re-create virtual functions (or interface) by hand but some clarification could help answering the question.

Comment: You can't create instances of static classes so you need to clarify what the goal is here.

Comment: static member cannot implement the interface too. You should consider not using static class.

Comment: I'm trying to create a collection of these controls that all have the same interface (member functions) so I can add all the controls to a list and do *.setup() for each item in the list. I guess I have to do it with an abstract class?

Comment: Oh I always thought static WAS a singleton, just a single object created at runtime. :) Today the model broke haha. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a type as a method parameter. Making the `PCM1_Setup` class non-static and all its methods instance methods (without the `static` modifier) and passing a new instance of the class as the parameter for `abe.Add` will solve the problem.

Alternatively, you can make `abe` of type `List<Type>` and use the `typeof` operator to add a reference to the type of the `PCM1_Setup` class.

```
List<Type> abe = new List<Type>();

PC2()
{
    abe.Add(typeof(PCM1_Setup));
}
```

Then you can call any of its methods using the `Type.GetMethod` function (that's reflection):

```
foreach (Type T in abe)
{
    if (T == typeof(PCM1_Setup))
    {
        T.GetMethod("Setup_toBFC").Invoke(null, null);
    }    
}
```

Keep in mind the example above it's not the best option and you'd be better off using the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a static class. So you never have instance of it that can be added to the list. If you want to have a single instance and access it without creating a new instance every time you need it you can implement some form of a singleton. Then you can add the instance of the singleton to the list.

```
public class PCM1_Setup : IGUI_to_BFC
{
    private static PCM1_Setup instance;

    public static PCM1_Setup Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new PCM1_Setup();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    private PCM1_Setup()
    {

    }

    ...
}
```

PCM1_Setup class is no longer static. The method should also be implemented as instance methods.
Then you add a singleton instance to the list from your example:

```
public static class PC2
{
    static List<IGUI_to_BFC> abe = new List<IGUI_to_BFC>();
    static PC2()
    {
        abe.Add(PCM1_Setup.Instance);
    }
}
```

Note that the constructor of the PC2 class has to be static as well since the class is static.

One issue with implementing the list of `IGUI_to_BFC` type is that when accessing items from the list you have to cast the instance to the child class type:

```
((PCM1_Setup)abe[0]).Setup_fromBFC();
```